# Unison systemd service exits with status code 3

Tags: systemd, services, unison

I'm trying to create a systemd service for unison, using the following `unison.system` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unison Sync
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/adamfg/bin/unison default
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
Type=simple
User=root
Environment=HOME=/home/adamfg/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=unison.service
```

Here is my `default.prf` file located in `/home/adamfg/.unison`:

```
root = /home/adamfg/workplace
root = ssh://adamfg@my-server.com//home/adamfg/workplace

{Some Ignore Rules}

ignorecase = false
repeat = watch
log = true
logfile = /home/adamfg/.unison/unison.log
backup = Name *
maxbackups = 5
retry = 1
auto = true
batch = true
confirmbigdeletes = true
times = true
prefer = newer
terse = true
contactquietly = true
silent = true
```

If I run `/home/adamfg/bin/unison default` unison will start and continue fine.

However when I try to run unison using `systemctl start unison.service` and then I query the state using `systemctl status unison.service` I get the following:

```
unison.service - Unison Sync
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/unison.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-10-07 09:14:25 IST; 884ms ago
  Process: 14607 ExecStart=/home/adamfg/bin/unison default (code=exited, status=3)
Main PID: 14607 (code=exited, status=3)
```

How can I fix this so I able to run unison as a systemd service?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that unison was unable to determine the location of the ssh private key file when running as a service, but it automatically uses the default one for your user if you run in from the command line.

To fix this I added the following line to my `default.prf` file:

```
sshargs= -oIdentityFile=/path/tos/ssh/key/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

The locks at both machines was preventing unison to start.
Deleting both locks helped fix it.

```
unison -ui text
Fatal error: Warning: the archives are locked.
If no other instance of unison is running, the locks should be removed.
The file <file_URI> on host <hostname> should be deleted
The file <file_URI> on host <hostname> should be deleted
Please delete lock files as appropriate and try again.
```